# Prove $f$ has inverse $f^{-1}$ in a neighborhood of the point $(1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$f(u,v)=(u^2+u^2v+10v,u+v^3).$$

a) Prove $f$ has inverse $f^{-1}$ in a neighborhood of the point $(1,1)$;

b) Find an aproximate value of $f^{-1}(11.8,2.2)$.

**My work:**

Note $$f'(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}
2u+2uv &1\\
u^2+10 &3v^2
\end{pmatrix},$$
then $$\det(f'(u,v))=(2u+uv)(3v^2)-(u^2+10)=6uv^2+3uv^3-u^2-10=0\\\iff6uv^2+3uv^3-u^2=10\\\iff3u(2v^2+v^3-u)=10\\\iff 2v^2+v^3-u=10.$$

Suppose $2v^2+v^3-u\not = 10$, then $$\det(f'(u,v))\not =0,$$ whis implies $f'(u,v)$ is invertible.

Moreover, note $f$ is of class $C^1$ then by inverse theorem function we have: there exists an open set $U=B((1,1),r)$ with $r=1-ε$ such that $f|_U$ is injective and have local inverse.

I don't know how to make the part b). Can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: $f(x+h) \approx f(x) + Df(x)h$ and the inverse function theorem tells you what $(Df)^{-1}$ is, and you know that $f(1,1) = (12,2)$.

Comment: Just as a trivial side note, once you take the derivative, you can put the values in immediately.  The determinant is a lot easier to evaluate numerically than symbolically.

Comment: Yes @Paul is correct.

Comment: I don't think the last equivalence ($\iff$) holds as it is written.